# Highlighting individual citations within a multi-citation

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I have a number of multi-citation `\cite{ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4...}`, where I would like to highlight some of them, e.g. ref2 and  ref4 in the example above. The highlighting could be a star and/or with a bold font, i.e. [1, 2*, 3, 4*],  [1, **2**, 3, **4**], or [1, **2***, 3, **4***].

(I am using Bibtex, if that has any importance here...)

Anyone who knows, whether this is possible?